# Can't read google sheets API by column (vertically) in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am using C# to query google sheets API.

I cannot seem to be able to query the MajorDimension = "COLUMNS" correctly

I have tried using the  service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get() function and using the value ranges.

```
ValueRange valueRange = new ValueRange();
valueRange.MajorDimension = "COLUMNS";//"ROWS";//COLUMNS
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest department_request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get("SPREADSHEETID", "SHEET_NAME");
ValueRange departments_response = department_request.Execute();
```

Now I have tried:

```
BatchGetValuesByDataFilterRequest body = new BatchGetValuesByDataFilterRequest();
DataFilter df = new DataFilter();
IList<DataFilter> filters = null;
filters.Add(df);
body.MajorDimension = "COLUMNS";
body.DataFilters = filters;
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.BatchGetByDataFilterRequest req= service.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchGetByDataFilter(body, "SPREADSHEETID");
req.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
 department_request.MajorDimension =  SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest.MajorDimensionEnum.COLUMNS;     
 SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest department_request = 
 service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get("SPREADSHEETID", "SHEET_NAME");
 ValueRange departments_response = department_request.Execute();
```